# req.user is undefined after passport.authenticate

Tags: javascript, express, axios, passport.js

I'm having issues getting access to req.user after I login. The passport authentication works and I initially get the req.user information to send to the client side after logging in but it becomes undefined immediately after.[Here is a picture of the console showing this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrsSX.png) How can I stop req.user form being undefined after logging in? It looks like it is in the session for a brief moment after the initial login. I've spent hours for fixes but nothing seems to work.

Below is how I handle the login.

```js
router.post(
    '/login',
    function (req, res, next) {
        next()
    },
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login' }),
     async (req, res) => {

         const fullUser = await User.findOne({ username: req.user.username })

         console.log(req.user)
         console.log(req.session)
         
        res.send(fullUser);
    }
)
```

Below is the server setup.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const User = require('./models/user');
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users-routes');
const chirpsRoutes = require('./routes/chirps-routes');
const singleRoutes = require('./routes/single-routes');
const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

const connectUrl = 'mongodb info removed';

mongoose.connect(connectUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Database connected");
});


// const connectConfig = {
//     useNewUrlParser: true,
//     useCreateIndex: true,
//     useUnifiedTopology: true,
//     useFindAndModify: false
// }

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //used to parse req.body


const secret = process.env.SECRET || 'thishouldbeabettersecret!';

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    url: connectUrl,
    secret,
    touchAfter: 24 * 60 * 60
});

store.on("error", function (e) {
    console.log("SESSION STORE ERROR", e)
})

const sessionConfig = {
    name: 'session',
    secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}

app.use(session(sessionConfig))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

//Add user to session
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
//Remove user from session
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // res.locals.currentUser = req.user; //passport user
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); //set header on resposne
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-Width, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'); //incoming requests handle
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
    console.log('******REQ.USER******' + " " + req.user)
    
    console.log('******SESSION BELOW******')
    console.log(req.session)
    next();
})


app.use('/auth', usersRoutes)
app.use('/chirps', chirpsRoutes)
app.use('/:uid', singleRoutes)


app.use((req, res, next) => { //error handling for invalid routes
    const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route.', 404);
    return next(error);
})


app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    if (res.headerSent) {
        return next(error);
    }
    res.status(error.code || 500);
    res.send({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred!' });
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serving on port ${port}`)
})
```

Below is the User schema.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    about: String
});

//add username & password to UserSchema
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And lastly, below is my login post request that I handle with React.

```js
 function loginUser(username, password) {
    try {
      const data = {
        username,
        password
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          if (response.status === 200) {
            auth.login(response.data._id,response.data.username)
            history.push('/chirps');
          }
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't use runnable snippet formatting for code that can't run in the browser. Also, remember to prime your code for your post: `function (req, res, next) { next() }` does nothing, so just leave it off.

Comment: Just checked here: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/ . Considering you are using the same local strategy, they have it a bit different. They defined their strategy (I don't see that in posted code) and then they just specify to use local strategy instead of having this async function on their router. Did you maybe try to follow approach on this page?

Comment: This is a long shot but did you figure this out? I'm dealing with the same problem